# Add UISwipeGestureRecognition to a custom View ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am trying to add `UISwipeGestureRecognition` to a custom View. I would like to do the same as IOS notifications but in the other way. I did it before with `tapGesture`, but when I add try with swipe, it does not work.

I am using this code. It is a hidden tableView that I display when I do a `swipeUp` with one finger.

**My problem now is that the view goes up but behind the main view.**

```
 -(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    headerLabel.tag = section;
    headerLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor salmonUser];
    headerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Interesteds"];
    headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(100, 0,  120,tableView.tableHeaderView.frame.size.height);
    [headerLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];


    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *upRecognizer= [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
    [upRecognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp)];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *downRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
    [downRecognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown)];

    [headerLabel addGestureRecognizer:upRecognizer];
    [headerLabel addGestureRecognizer:downRecognizer];

    return headerLabel;

    //return nil;
}



- (void)handleSwipeFrom:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSUserDefaults *d = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    BOOL switchUpDown = [d boolForKey:@"switchUpDown"];


    UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection up = switchUpDown ? UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp : UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
    UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection down = switchUpDown ? UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown : UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;

    if (recognizer.direction == up){

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                              delay:0.3
                            options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{
                             CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
                             rect.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height-(self.view.frame.size.height/2);
                             self.usersView.frame = rect;
                             mostrada =true;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
    } else if(recognizer.direction == down){

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                              delay:0.3
                            options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{
                             CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
                             rect.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height-(self.view.frame.size.height/11);
                             self.usersView.frame = rect;
                             mostrada=false;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){

                         }];
    }

}
```

Comment: So the view that the gesture is connected to isn't actually on screen?

Comment: Just a word of advice... It's a lot easier to figure out problems with your code, when it's easily read. This code is a mess

Comment: @wain it is connected I already did the same with tapGesture, but this does not work

Comment: @CodeBandits How should I improve my code? Do you think it is really a mess? There is no much code here...

Comment: just the way you laid it out. Your edit improved it quite a bit, you had random spaces between text and `}` put in strange spots which made the code hard to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use This code :

```
 -(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    headerLabel.tag = section;
    headerLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor salmonUser];
    headerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Interesteds"];
    headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(100, 0,  120,tableView.tableHeaderView.frame.size.height);
    [headerLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(upSwipe:)];
            [swipeLeft setDirection: UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp ];
            [headerLabel addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
            swipeLeft=nil;

            UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(downSwipe:)];
            [swipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown];
            [headerLabel addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];

    return headerLabel;

}
```

> I have used two different method to take action individually for up and down swipe as `upSwipe` and `downSwipe`. This will simplefy the code.

```
-(void)upSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                              delay:0.3
                            options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{
                             CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
                             rect.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height-(self.view.frame.size.height/2);
                             self.usersView.frame = rect;
                             mostrada =true;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
}

-(void)downSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                              delay:0.3
                            options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{
                             CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
                             rect.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height-(self.view.frame.size.height/11);
                             self.usersView.frame = rect;
                             mostrada=false;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){

                         }];
}
```

Comment: I don't know why but is not I working, I also think this solution before. I have tried this one too and nothing..

Comment: What exactly the problem is?

Comment: it is weird, sometimes it works and sometimes it is behind the main view.. I think that maybe I can set all the tableview in a new custom view with header "Interesteds" and inside this view add the table view. Because I think it seems to be a problem of swipe a tableview at the same time

Comment: OK than before swipe means in the handleSwipe method add headerView on the MainView first. So to do that you should get first the rect of headerView with respact to mainView. Do you got my logic?

Answer (score 0):

Change your method to this:

```
-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
    UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    headerLabel.tag = section;
    headerLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor salmonUser];
    headerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Interesteds"];
    headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(100, 0,  120,tableView.tableHeaderView.frame.size.height);
    [headerLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];


    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *upRecognizer= [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
    [upRecognizersetDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp)];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *downRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
    [downRecognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown)];

    [headerLabel addGestureRecognizer:upRecognizer];
    [headerLabel addGestureRecognizer:downRecognizer];

    return headerLabel;

    //return nil;
}
```

Comment: My problem now is that the view goes up but behind the main view